# Having issues installing qemu, pixman autoreconfig missing

Tags: 12.04, make, qemu

i dont understand this error message from the "make" function.

> qemu-1.7.0-rc1/pixman; autoreconf -v --install)
>
> /bin/sh: 1: autoreconf: not found make: ***
>   [/home/alex/Desktop/qemu-1.7.0-rc1/pixman/configure] Error 127

how would i get this to work?
do i install pixman or autoreconfig?